# How to Encrypt Clipboard?

Tags: security, clipboard

Can the contents of the clipboard be encrypted?

For example, say that to circumvent keyloggers, users copy and paste passwords from an encrypted file, but now the password lives unencrypted in the clipboard. Is there a way to prevent this behavior without breaking copy/paste, or running some script function that scrambles the clipboard information.

Comment: Where did you copy the password *from*? Didn't it exist unencrypted there too?

Comment: @Longpoke i'm pretty sure it involves a blender.

Comment: Why the close votes? If mike wants to implement a Windows tool that automatically encrypts clipboard contents, this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Heinzi I guess i'm more objectionable to the security tag.  In security you defend against an attacker,  what attack does this stop?  Answer:  absolutely nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, some were funny. I was just wondering if it is possible or not, and I mentioned the keylogger just as an example. To me it is a security question because there may be an attack that captures the clipboard history, instead of just capturing key strokes.

Comment: I am not sure why this was closed as off topic, perhaps it was asked in the wrong place. Regardless, it is a good question. Any background application can monitor and store clipboard changes, so it is even worse than the threat of keyloggers, to copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your question**: It should be possible, but you'd need to dig quite deep into the Windows API for that.

- To catch *COPY* events and encrypt the contents, you could use [`SetClipboardViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get notified of changed to the clipboard. [Here](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx) is an example on how to do this with C#.
- To catch *PASTE* events and decrypt the contents, you might need to globally hook to `WM_PASTE` messages.

**As a side note**: Once a keylogger/trojan/etc. managed to run on your system, it is no longer your system. Encrypting the clipboard or similar techniques don't protect your system, they might just raise the bar for the malware developer to get the information he wants (see Jean-Bernard's answer). Preventing evil code from running on your system in the first place is a much better approach.

Comment: Agreed, it will stop a generic wide scale attack, due to the halting problem, but not someone specifically targeting you.

Comment: I'll look into the C# example. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Some programs will monitor and store clipboard history. These are a 'bigger problem' regarding password copy pasting, as it will smear your passwords across multiple places in memory as well as opening more possibilities for your password getting exposed.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to supply the unencrypted password to a textfield in order to sign in, then nothing you do before that step can stop malicious users from reading the contents of that textbox. Since there needs to be a point in time where that plaintext string is sent to the textbox.

I think if you have a keylogger you have more important problems than encrypting passwords

Comment: Thansk Jean. I was reading about KeyScrambler, which made me wonder about the clipboard. Since I use KeePass, I don't type many passwords, but I do copy/paste a lot.

Comment: From what I understand, not all api's store the text in textfields as plain-text at all, but character arrays instead, I assume, so that the string of characters are not continuous in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If the clipboard information is persisted to the drive then whole disk encryption would do the trick (it sounds like that's the kind of stuff you want to do already anyway based on the question).

But encrypting what's in RAM isn't really an option.  At some point the OS and applications read that memory and need to know what to do with it.  It has to be unencrypted *somewhere* in the active hardware of the machine in order to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly encrypt the data, copy it to the clipboard, and then in another instance of your app, paste it, decrypt it.  But this is only useful if the source/destination agree on the encryption. i.e. written by the same guy.  In that case, you'd be better off NOT using the clipboard, and setting up some sort of private data channel instead.
So while you can do it, it's not practical.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by encrypting your data for your application before the copy, but it really depends on the language you would use.

And decrypt on the paste, but again on your application. You can't do that for all your system; it would mean modifications on your OS...

Comment: "requires modifications to the OS" != "can't be done". The Windows API provides a lot of hooks to modify the system behavior...

Comment: That would be huge to create applications that lurks the clipboard.

Comment: Lurking the clipboard is actually not that hard: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx

Comment: This is really creepy. Isn't that considered as a security breach ???

Comment: no. Every program in Windows has full privileges, UAC and ACLs try to prevent this, but there are too many other fundamental flaws in Windows' design for it to work. It's a **rare** case that you can run a program in a non-privileged context these days, especially in Windows..

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing an application which implements copy-and-paste: therefore I use a system API to read data from the clipboard.

If I can't read unencrypted data then copy-and-paste is broken, but if I can then so could any other installed program (including a keylogger).

Answer (score 0):

If someone has privileges to install a keylogger that has clipboard access, he most likely has privileges to get the decryption key of the clipboard as well. Cryptography is not a substitute for access control.